# Re-install motd after /motd-update directory has been cleaned

Tags: linux

I have the following problem. I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 and I deleted the contents of /etc/motd-update folder. I want to simply add a custom ssh custom login message, I don't need the other files. What filename should I add to /etc/motd-update to accomplish this? thank you!

Comment: Can someone at least post the contents of the directory so I can fix this manually? Thanks!